# SHA1 в android app

Tags: android, android-studio, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Есть приложение андроид с авторизацией через ВК. 
Вот данные в ВК приложении: `id = 51616`, этот же `id` и в `AS`;пакет - by.mycompany.app- соответственно и в приложении AS. SHA1 - совпадают так же.(`SHA1` получил через добавленную активность `GoogleMaps`). При дебаге на реальном устройстве все работает. Но при сборке апк и установке - НЕТ. Может, будут какие-нибудь идеи.
И сама ошибка:

> error:invalid request;error_description: sdk_fingerprints is
>   incorrect;

Ранее проект собирался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду, что у вас не работает выложенное в маркет приложение, то дело тут в том, что надо добавить SHA-1 релизного ключа, которым вы подписывали приложение при выкладывании в маркет

С помощью VKSDK отпечатки ключей можно получить так (this - это `Context`):

```
String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());
for(String sha1: fingerprints) {
    Log.d("VK_SDK", "sha01: " + sha1);
}
```

Comment: Это будет не обновление, а новая версия в новой панели плэй маркета.

Comment: Я собрал АПК и установил на телефон. И вот при авторизации ошибка.

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, старайтесь более формализовано обозначать свою проблему. В данный момент вы нам сообщили, что у вас при дебаге всё работало, а теперь не работает из-за некорректного ключа. Вариантов тут может быть много, так что постарайтесь более подробно проблему в вопросе описать. В т.ч. приведите по пуктам процесс воспроизведения ошибки и в какой момент и при каких действиях она возникла.

Comment: да какие тут варианты ))) собрал apk хочешь выложить в маркет подпиши release SHA-1, не хочешь выкладывать а просто дебажить, подпиши debug SHA-1. Сменил package apk, получай новый ключ

Comment: Настроил приложение так как описал в вопросе. Далее запустил на дебаг. Работает. Собрал АПК с ключем - авторизация не проходит по данной ошибке(та что в вопросе).

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, так я же вам написал, что надо в ВК добавить ещё один SHA-1. Т.е. там должно быть два ключа - дебажный и релизный

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, пакет менял, а SHA-1 остался тот же. Как еще можно ли сменить SHA-1. Если да, то каким образом???

Comment: в студии есть быстрый способ, справа в gradle в root выберите singReport он вам покажет и релизный и дебажный, если не получиться загуглите в сети сейчас много ответов на это, ну мб кто на русском ответи, тоже было бы приятно.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei release - NONE. Хотя я его собирал.

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, получить отпечатки ключей можно так: `String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName())`